# C - write data to a file, either write all or write nothing

Tags: c

In my case, writing partial data is nonsense, so I figure out this:

```
ssize_t write_all(int fd, unsigned char* data, size_t size) {
    ssize_t w;
    size_t written = 0;
    unsigned char* buf = data;

    do {
        w = write(fd, buf, size-written);
        if (w > 0) {
            written += w;
            if (written == size) {
                return written;
            } else {
                buf += w;
            }
        } else {
            lseek(fd, SEEK_CUR, -written);
            return 0;
        }
    } while (1);
}
```

Is this correct? Or are there any better practices?

Comment: Do you expect the file to be opened with `O_APPEND` (see [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html)
)?  If so, the [`lseek()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lseek.html) won't help, but [`ftruncate()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftruncate.html) could be used to remove the added data.  Actually, unless you are writing into the middle (or the very start) of a file, using `ftruncate()` is probably what you need.

Comment: Also, if the write fails, it is not clear that you should seek backwards by the amount you tried to write.  You probably need to track where your code is about to write (capture the result of `lseek(fd, SEEK_CUR, 0);` — and hope no other process is writing using the same open file description).

Comment: One common way to do this is to write to a tmp file and then use  [`rename`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) to move it to the target file.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I would do:

1. create a temporary file somewhere convenient (like `/tmp`)
2. write out that file until you reach the point where you can declare the operation a success
3. unlink the original and move the new file to the same location/name.

Once you call `write()` you are at the mercy of the kernel as far as when the data will actually be flushed to the disk.

You can use `O_SYNC` to add a level of assurance that the data has been written - `O_SYNC` will cause `write()` to block until the data is written to disk. `O_DSYNC` has the same behavior, but it will block until all of the file-system metadata is written as well, giving a stronger guarantee that the data will be retrievable once `write()` returns.

Comment: You can use options like `O_SYNC`, `O_DSYNC` and `O_RSYNC` to [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) in order to get some more control over when the data is securely written.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler good point, i updated with `O_SYNC` / `O_DSYNC` details